# Appending elements to a list containing empty lists

Tags: python, append, empty-list

Let's say I create a list containing empty lists:

```
ex_list = [[], [], [], [], []]
```

How do I append elements to the specific empty lists contained in `ex_list`?

For example, I would expect that:

```
ex_list[0].append("a")
```

would return:

```
ex_list = [[a], [], [], [], []]
```

But it returns:

```
[['a'], ['a'], ['a'], ['a'], ['a']]
```

Comment: Are you sure that's how you're initializing `ex_list`? The example you show works as you expected for me.

Comment: [Works on my machine](http://ideone.com/hOtJF4).

Comment: `>>> ex_list = [[], [], [], [], []]
>>> ex_list[0].append(1)
>>> ex_list
[[1], [], [], [], []]`

Comment: Are you sure you didn't do `ex_list = [[]]*4`?

Comment: He obviously did not initialize the list like that. And this have been answered countless times before

Comment: You need to use deep copy: https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy

Comment: @JanVlcinsky either the asker wrote the code they said they wrote, in which case the outcome is as expected and there is no problem to solve, or they wrote the code described in the duplicate and they can find their answer there.

Comment: @murgatroid99 You are right. senderle have seen a bit deeper then me, and his decision to mark it as duplicate was good one.